# CAS server, how to "synchronize" use of the app (the user session) and PGT expiration

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I'm facing a problem with my CAS server.

A user connects to an app, by using a ST. The app asks for a PGT. Until now, no problem. The user do his stuff in the app, sometimes calling casified-webservice, thus asking CAS for a PT. Sometimes the user doesn't use the webservice during, for example 2 hours (TGT/PGT default expiration time), but still use actively the app. When 3 hours later (for example) the app asks for a PT for the webservice, the PGT is expired, I'm getting `PHPCAS_SERVICE_PT_FAILURE` error and the user MUST be disconnected to get another valid PGT.

It's a bit awkward having to disconnect the user while the user have been active during all this time.

Is there any solution ? How to "synchronize" use of the app (the user session) and PGT expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS 4.3 will allow you to set an expiration policy for PGTs that may be different from the normal TGT expiration policy. Also, when PGT is used the parent TGT is also updated to ensure inactivity does not kill the session.